# Rotate log file for every 100 MB size

Tags: batch-file

I have windows batch script which starts a java process. This process runs for a week, the problem is ow a days log file of this process is very huge(around 10 GB). I am facing problem while opening this log file in editor like NotePad++, EditPlus and TextPad.
Please can I get command to add in my start up batch script for rotating log file when size reaches to 100 mb. It would be a great help.

Comment: I am logging using log4j.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logging in log4j you can configure the max file size. See a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212679/configure-log4j-for-maxsize-and-rotation)

e.g. In the java (rather than the batch file) or in log4j's configuration file *using a suitable max size):

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped. But I see that File name is not in sync with the one which get created with batch script. With Batch Script Naming convention is ProcessName_%DT%-%TM%.log whereas with log4j.appender.File=ProcessName.log.it just give me the name which is provided to this property. I tried with "${PROCESS_NAME}_${CURRENT_TIME}.log" it didn't help. Any thoughts